# What ffmpeg command will produce a video compression similar to Instagram's compression?

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, instagram, video-compression

I am looking to take a video and compress it in a way that is similar to the compression that Instagram uses. What ffmpeg command can do this?

Comment: What samples are you trying to match?

Comment: I noticed that for an 18s video, they compress it so that it's only 1.16mb. I am having trouble achieving a comparable rate. My current best using ffmpeg is 30x that.

Comment: Source video and command? Insta video link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instagram currently uses x264 to encode video, and the single video I looked at was cropped to 640x640 and had no audio.

## Get file info

The encoding information was not removed from the sample so you can probe it to infer what encoding options were used.

```
$ strings input.mp4 | grep x264
x264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=0 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=8 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=1638 vbv_bufsize=3276 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=2:1.00
```

Alternatively you can use `mediainfo` to get this info.

## Encode

Basically the default settings (`-crf 23` `-preset medium`) are being used in my sample with a few additional options:

```
ffmpeg -i input -maxrate 1638k -bufsize 3276k -psy 0 -aq-mode 2 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- I would not bother with copying these settings verbatim (especially `-psy 0`), and would experiment with a simpler command to see what works best for your needs. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).
- This example doesn't perform the cropping. See the [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) and/or [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filters to do that.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. That command alone takes my 30x comparison to 12.5x. I'll play with it some to achieve a better rate.

Comment: @user592419 When you upload the same source to Instagram is it a similar result?